# How to center widgets in a grid - GTK C

Tags: c, button, grid, widget, gtk

I'm trying to center these buttons in a this grid but I've tried set_hexpand and variants and nothing's what I'm looking for.

```c
GtkWidget *p_main_grid = gtk_grid_new();

   gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_main_grid), 16);
   gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(p_main_grid), 16);

   /* Buttons */

   GtkWidget *p_button_1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button 1");
   GtkWidget *p_button_2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button 2");

   /* Add Buttons to grid */

   gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(p_main_grid), p_button_1, 5, 3, 1, 1);
   gtk_grid_attach_next_to(GTK_GRID(p_main_grid), p_button_2, p_button_1,
                           GTK_POS_RIGHT, 1, 1);

   /* Add grid to main window */

   gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(p_main_window), p_main_grid);
   gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(p_main_window));
```

I'm on linux and using gtk4

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in gtk3 and it centered two buttons.
This tries to use 10 columns and 10 rows.
The spacing of 16 seems to provide some distance between the buttons.

```
    grid = gtk_grid_new ( );
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 16);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 16);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous ( GTK_GRID ( grid), TRUE);
    gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous ( GTK_GRID ( grid), TRUE);

    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

    //blank label to take up 2 cols by 10 rows on left
    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 0, 0, 2, 10);

    //blank lable to take up 6 cols by 4 rows at top center
    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 2, 0, 6, 4);

    //buttons 3 cols by 1 row each placed below the top center blank label
    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "button 1");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button1, 2, 4, 3, 1);
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "button 2");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button2, 5, 4, 3, 1);

    //blank label to take up 2 cols by 10 rows on right
    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 8, 0, 2, 10);
```

This is working with 4 cols by 3 rows

```
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( GTK_WINDOW ( window), 400, 200);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ( );
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 16);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 16);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous ( GTK_GRID ( grid), TRUE);
    gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous ( GTK_GRID ( grid), TRUE);

    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    //blank label to take up 2 cols by 10 rows on left
    // gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 0, 0, 2, 10);
    //blank label to take up 1 cols by 3 rows on left
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 0, 0, 1, 3);

    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    //blank lable to take up 6 cols by 4 rows at top center
    // gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 2, 0, 6, 4);
    //blank lable to take up 2 cols by 1 rows at top center
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 1, 0, 2, 1);

    //buttons 3 cols by 1 row each placed below the top center blank label
    button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "button 1");
    // gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button1, 2, 4, 3, 1);
    //buttons 1 cols by 1 row each placed below the top center blank label
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ( "button 2");
    // gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button2, 5, 4, 3, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), button2, 2, 1, 1, 1);

    title = gtk_label_new ( "");
    //blank label to take up 2 cols by 10 rows on right
    // gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 8, 0, 2, 10);
    //blank label to take up 1 cols by 3 rows on right
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID ( grid), title, 3, 0, 1, 3);
```

Comment: Ok that worked, thanks, but whats the trick? Where does the amount of rows and columns come from? Do grids have a default amount of these? In case I wanna add more buttons and center these, too. Im pretty new to desktop apps and grids and these things im making a desktop app for college

Comment: man tysm, you are nice i  finally got how it works